# New Win32 Application Wizard is blank

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I try to create a new Win32 Console Application or Win32 Project, the Win32 Application Wizard pops up with the project setting bullet points empty and the "Application Settings," "Finish," and "Cancel" buttons unable to be clicked.

When I searched for answered questions similar to mine, the solution that meant reinstalling after using CCleaner, didn't work.

Comment: The content of that dialog is a WebBrowser, the text is rendered by Javascript.  You'll need to get your machine fixed and disable or repair whatever prevents JS from running.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it appeared in an old Visual Studio version after installing VS Community 2015 on the same 64-bit Windows machine. The installer of VS Community 2015 creates a bunch of new and alters existing registry hacks that mshtml.dll uses to deal with executables with specific names, in our case with devenv.exe. These hacks are (in 64-bit Windows) located at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl
```

So inside this FeatureControl branch I just had to change the value of DWORD parameter

```
FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN\devenv.exe
```

from 1 to 0, and then I could immediately create new projects in Visual Studio. This FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN hack changes the Internet Explorer's "security zone", in which devenv.exe operates, while from the revelations of some of Visual Studio authors we know that "wizards" in old Visual Studios always ran in their special "security zone" with a unique identifier "1000", which let them enjoy very lax security settings. So VS Community 2015 effectively prevented JavaScript from running in an old Visual Studio's internal web browser (vsbrowse.dll, I believe?). Please note that the suppression of JavaScript may have a completely different cause in your case, and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for that is that Console application doesn't have most of the options available for Win32 / MFC projects. There are no windows, dialogs or other elements to define. 
However, Console applications still have:
- Precompiled header (yes / no)
- Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) checks  (yes / no)
You can still build a Console application with ATL and MFC common headers.
[image]

Comment: You are answering some different question, not what OP has asked.